# Fast way to test whether a point is over a 3D mesh

Tags: algorithm, unreal-4, 3d-meshes, projection

I have a map with islands, and I need to detect whether the player is on an island or not.

The player can be flying far above the island, so a fixed-distance raycast is not sufficient, and firing long raycasts has worse performance than I want.

My idea is to parallel project the static mesh of island on some surface to get its shape from top-down view. Then I can check if the player position is in that polygon.

For example, I could draw the polygon to a texture, filled with a specific solid color. Then I can check corresponding pixel colour to detect whether the current coordinate is on an island or not.

But how can I actually implement this?

Comment: Is an axis aligned bounding box sufficient resolution for being over an island?

Comment: @GaleRazorwind Islands are random shaped

Comment: How do you determine what mesh or part of a mesh constitutes an island? Do you need to know precisely if the player is above an island or is it okay if they are just close to being over one? How is your island mesh aligned in the editor? Is it a uniform grid mesh? I think you have simpler and easier ways of knowing when you above the islands. Why do you need to know if the player is above an island? What are you hoping to trigger?

Comment: Do you have any idea what the reason is the raycast detection takes too long? Are you iterating over all triangles or are there too many objects? Have you tried putting the islands into a quad-tree and do a broad scan first? Also if the islands and the player are in the same coordinate space, a boundingbox check would be trivial to reduce the number of candidate islands to check.